# Explicit song lyrics checker

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, file

To stay in practice with my Python I've decided to write an explicit song checker. It checks each word in the song against an array of 14 explicit words contained in the text file. I've decided not to include the words that are to be checked against, for I am [not sure about the rule of having explicit words in a program's code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9209). Feedback on efficiency and structure is what I'm going for mostly. Style and other critiques are invited as well.

**explicit_song_checker.py**

```
explicit_words = [
    #explicit words not shown 
]

def isClean(song_path):
    with open(song_path) as song:
        for line in song:
            words = line.split(" ")
            for word in words:
                for explicit_word in explicit_words:
                    if word == explicit_word:
                        return False

        return True

def main():
    song = raw_input("Enter path to song: \n")
    if isClean(song):
        print("CLEAN")
    else:
        print("EXPLICIT")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The only tiny thing (not big enough for an answer, IMHO) I want to add to all the great answers already given, is about naming variables. It should be clear from the name what a variable contains. What does another programmer expect that a variable named `song` contains? It cannot be a song, because that is something that you hear. So probably the lyrics then? Or the file? Ah, the *path* to the *file* that contains the *lyrics* of the song. I would try to make variable names as "explicit" as possible ;-) So `song_path` (as used in the function) is already much better :-)

Comment: As a counterexample, check out the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) for what can happen if your check is overzealous…

Comment: Not sure if scope creeping the review, but would be nice if your script could take a path to a folder and print all songs inside it.

Comment: why not use a dictionary and some sort of hash. a linear search would be horrible

Comment: There is a [meta CR post that involves this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9209/120114)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recommend practicing Python 3 rather than Python 2 these days.

According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), `isClean()` should be `is_clean()`.

One or more of your loops could be replaced by some use of the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function.  Note that this suggests that an `is_explicit()` function would be a more natural concept than an `is_clean()` function.

I would expect song lyrics to contain a mixture of uppercase and lowercase.  Words may be delimited by punctuation as well as spaces.  Therefore, `words = line.split(" ")` is probably too naïve.  Furthermore, I would expect each song to be short enough to fit entirely in memory very comfortably, so processing each file line by line is an unnecessary complication.

I would rewrite the program to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) instead.

```
import re

explicit_words = [
    …
]

is_explicit = re.compile(
    r'\b(?:' +
        '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in explicit_words) +
    r')\b',
    re.IGNORECASE).search

def main():
    with open(raw_input("Enter path to song: ")) as song:
        print("EXPLICIT" if is_explicit(song.read()) else "CLEAN")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The way I chose to write the `is_explicit()` function above might show too much Haskell influence for some Python programmers' taste.  Here's a more conventional way of writing it:

```
def is_explicit(text):
    return re.search(
        r'\b(?:' +
            '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in explicit_words) +
        r')\b',
        text,
        re.IGNORECASE
    )
```

Comment: The regex answer has a variety of things I don't like. Firstly, this compiles the regex every time. 2nd, regex has no guarantees of O(1) like a set would.

Comment: @OscarSmith The program calls the helper function once from `main()`, and the word list contains just 14 entries, so neither objection was a significant concern in this solution.

Comment: Oh, I was mainly commenting on the bottom block, where it's in the function.

Comment: I don't think using the regular expression makes this code any easier to understand. https://www.xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 21):

Splitting `line` into `words` using `words = line.split(" ")` will only split the line on space characters.  If two words are separated by a tab character, or other white space character other than a space, the split will not happen at that point, which may confuse your explicit checker.

Using `words = line.split()` would split on spaces, tab characters, and any other white space characters.

You might also want to investigate splitting using the word break regular expression `\b`, which would treat non-word characters as break points, so that a line containing an explicit word immediately followed by a comma (such as `"explicit,"`) or period, or semicolon, etc. won't sneak through the filter.

---

```
            for explicit_word in explicit_words:
                if word == explicit_word:
                    return False
```

Python has great searching built into it.  Instead of explicitly writing a loop over all explicit words, you could just ask Python to tell you if a word is in the list of explicit words:

```
            if word in explicit_words:
                return False
```

Or better, use a `set()` of explicit words, and the `in` operation drops from \$O(n)\$ to \$O(1)\$ time complexity:

```
explicit_words = {
    "explicit", "bad", "ugly", "offensive", "words" 
}

# ...

            if word in explicit_words:
                return False
```

---

We've improved things a little, but we still have an explicit (pun intended) loop over the list of words in a line.  We can use the `any()` method, and a list comprehension, to get Python to do the looping for us, which should be faster.

```
    for line in song:
        words = line.split()
        if any(word in explicit_words for word in words):
            return False
```

If `word in explicits` returns `True` for any of the `word` in the list `words`, the `any()` method will "short-circuit" and immediately return `True` without examining the remaining items in `words`.

---

If `"explicit"` is a bad word, and the song lyrics contains `"Explicit"` or `"EXPLICIT"`, you wouldn't want to mark the song as "CLEAN", right?  Perhaps you want `word.lower() in explicit_words`?   As @wizzwizz4 pointed out, `.casefold()` is better than `.lower()`.

---

Resulting method:

```
explicit_words = set(explicit_word.casefold()
    for explicit_word in ("explicit", "bad", "ugly", "offensive", "words"))

def isClean(song_path):
    with open(song_path) as song:
        for line in song:
            words = line.split()
            if any(word.casefold() in explicit_words for word in words):
                return False    
        return True
```

Comment: Why does it need to iterate over the song lines? `song.split()` would also split on `\n` (and `\r`, of course). Call me unpythonic, but I would directly `return any(word.lower() in explicit_words for word in song.split())`

Comment: @Helio I expect you would need `song.read().split()`, not `song.split()`.   As for why I didn’t?  I considered making it one-statement, and decided against doing so because the `split()` doesn’t consider punctuation as word separators.  That area still needed replacement with a regex `\b` style word splitting, so embedding it inside of the `any(...)` hides the work that still needed to be done.

Comment: yes, my bad; I've posted the comment thoughtlessly. A naïve alternative to regular expressions would be replacing punctuation symbols by spaces and then running `split`. However, that would be too clumsy. If this code is not an exercise, maybe the OP should use some specialized framework like NLTK.

Comment: Why not `str.casefold` instead of `str.lower`? They're the same for (most of) Latin, but different for stuff like Greek.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Fair point; well made.  All the words in `explicit_words` would need to be run through `casefold()` as well.

Answer (score 16):

Some suggestions:

- Using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parse arguments is preferable to any kind of interactive input, because it means that

  - it's much easier to automate and integrate in other scripts,
  - you could trivially support passing *multiple* songs in one command,
  - it's what any experienced shell user would expect, and
  - if the user adds `--help` or doesn't pass any arguments they will get a synopsis for the command.
- The list of explicit words should *not* be part of the code, because it is configuration and is very likely to change often. You'll want to put words in a separate file and read them in during initialization. You could very easily make this an optional argument (with `argparse`) so that you could do fancy stuff like `./explicit_song_checker.py --words=./words.txt --words=./other.txt ./kill-the-queen.txt ./bulls-on-parade.txt`
- [`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) will automatically format your code to be pretty idiomatic, such as using *two* empty lines between top-level functions.
- [`flake8`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8) will check for style issues. I believe it will assume that you're writing Python 3, and so will complain about the use of `raw_input` (called `input` in Python 3).
- [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy/) can be used to enforce type hints, which is a super helpful way to make your code clearer without resorting to comments.

Answer (score 4):

- To simplify your input you could change `word == explicit_word` to `explicit_word in word`.

  This can lead to the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), and so from here you can check if the word only contains prefixes and suffixes.

  Given [the amount of common prefixes alone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-formation/prefixes), it's unlikely you'd catch all variations using a blacklist alone. It would also catch gibberish/semigibberish that you may not have thought of - "Antioverfucked" / "Overantifucked".
- Your code misses words without spaces "I don't give afuck" and so you may want to perform a 'similarity check'.

  This could also match thinks like "sexx".
- Your code doesn't reasonably handle ZWSP and other forms of Unicode abuse.

  ```
  >>> print('exp\u200blitive')
  exp​litive
  >>> 'exp\u200blitive' == 'explitive'
  False
  >>> print('exp\u1DD3litive')
  expᷓlitive
  ```
- Your code doesn't reasonably detect leet speak.
- Your code doesn't reasonably detect creative Unicode character selections.

  ```
  >>> print('\u2131\u01DA\u0255\u212A')
  ℱǚɕK
  ```
- Your code doesn't reasonably handle phonetic abuse.

  "Phuck" is pronounced "Fuck".

  "Bend Dover" sounds like "bend over".

  "I CUP" spelt out is "I see you pee".

  "See you next Tuesday" each starting phonetic spells "CU...".

---

When I say doesn't reasonably, I mean if someone combined the above to get something ridiculous like "4n7ipᷓhǚ​ɕK" your word list would have to be ridiculous in size to match it.

It should also be fairly obvious that someone probably will find a way to bypass your check no matter what you do.

## Practicality vs Perfection

Given how widespread leet speak is you should handle that at a bare minimum. This is fairly easy, you just 'translate' from this alphabet. And perform the checks you're already doing.

You should then probably use a 'similar check' to match "sexx" or "afuck". This is as duplicating a letter or missing a space is readable and easy.
This check may result in problems as "Scunthorpe" could be understood as "s cunt thorp e" so would be split into two two known words and two extra letters, and then the similarity check my come back low enough to say it's a swearword.

From here ZWSP and other unicode abuse probably are the next most common. And with things like [`deasciiify`](https://pypi.org/project/deasciiify/) it's only getting easier.

Comment: Yeah, if catching explicit language was easy, you wouldn't have things like controversies over video game language filters getting over-aggressive and filtering out legitimate speech.

Comment: If you only check for prefixes and suffixes, you still have the Penistone and Cockfosters problems.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> explicit_words = [
>     #explicit words not shown 
> ]
> ```

Instead of embedding the word list within the program, you might want to treat it as *configuration*, and load it from a data file.  The advantage of this is that it can allow the use of alternative configurations by command-line option (e.g. use a list of French obscenities for French-language lyrics).

---

On efficiency: we're only interested in the *set* of words in the lyrics.  Given that many songs have repeated lyrics, then it's probably worth reducing the lyrics to a set of words before comparing that set with the banned words (use [`&`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) for set intersection), or [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) for a potentially faster test.

Answer (score 1):

The code feedback is already done wonderfully. I'd like to write about some pointers that might be important, apart from the leet speak:

- The word Phoque , is French for seal. There are numerous examples of words which are perfectly meaningful in some language but if pronounced in English, might be considered offensive. You might need to do a [phonetic similarity check](https://stackabuse.com/phonetic-similarity-of-words-a-vectorized-approach-in-python/)
- The context can be taken into account. For example, the word 'blow' or 'mom' need not be offensive. It becomes offensive only when it is surrounded by contextual words that make it offensive, ('job', etc).  In these cases, you might need to come up with an [algorithm that outputs a probability score](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-score-probability-predictions-in-python/) and filter songs based on that.

Comment: I'd like to take this up as a project. This has tremendous scope. For example, you can integrate this into the smartphones of kids . If youre interested, drop me a message